# Adding span tag in Rails link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I've looked on SO about how to add a `<span>` tag but I didn't see an example that placed the `<span>` where I want using Rails 3 `link_to`:

```
<a href="#" class="button white"><span id="span">My span&nbsp;</span>My data</a>
```

I tried something like:

```
<%= link_to(content_tag{:span => "My span&nbsp;", :id => "span"} @user.profile.my_data, "#", {:class => "button white"}) %>
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[`link_to` can take a block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) so I think you're after something like this:

```
<%= link_to '#', :class => 'button white' do %>
    <span id="span">My span&nbsp;</span><%= @user.profile.my_data %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: mu is too short, If you have a moment can you take a look at my follow-up to this. I want to add the value of the link you helped me produce to an array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564247/adding-items-to-rails-3-array-onclick

Answer (score 10):

A combination of the `.html_safe` with `#{@user.profile.my_data}` should work as well.

```
<%= link_to "<span id='span'>My span&nbsp;</span>#{@user.profile.my_data}".html_safe, "#", class: 'button white' %>
```

You can also use a `content_tag` so it would look like:

```
<%= link_to(content_tag(:span, "My span&nbsp;", id:"span")+"#{@user.profile.my_data}", "#", class: 'button white' %>
```

They're basically identical but one might be easier on the eyes for you. Also, I'm pretty new to coding so if this is dead wrong for some crazy reason, please just comment and I'll change it.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not wrong, but `link_to ... do` was meant for exactly this and it looks much better than your solution IMO.

Answer (score 5):

```
link_to '#', :class => 'button white' do
  <span id="span">My span&nbsp;</span>My data
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In HAML :

```
= link_to  new_post_mobile_path(topic.slug), class: 'add-new-place-btn' do
  %span{:class => "glyphicon glyphicon-plus", :style => "margin-right: 4px;"}
  New Place
```