# Rails 3 array - add items with category then list items in category

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

As part of my Rails 3 app, I want the User to be able to click on links on other profiles/pages and have the string value of the link be added to an array belonging to that User's profile.

Specifically, what I am looking to do is populate a list of `:todos` for each profile depending on which `todo` they click. The idea is that each `todo` will fall within one of two categories: inside and outside. So clicking the links will push the value of the `todo` to either inside or outside. Then the User's profile will display a list of `:todos` inside and outside, and count the total of `todos` for that User's profile.

Since I'm a beginner to programming, I got some help here on SO about setting this up; however I need some help finishing it. I can't quite seem to connect all the dots. I've set up a join model but am not able to add the todo's string value, then list/count it in the profile. Here is my code:

**profile.rb Model:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  has_many :profile_todos
  has_many :todos, :through => :profile_todos

  def add_todo_inside_item(item)
    self.profile_todos.build :category => 'inside'
  end

  def add_todo_outside_item(item)
    self.profile_todos.build :category => 'outside'
  end
end
```

**todo.rb Model:**

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

**profile_todo.rb Model:**

```
class ProfileTodo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :todo
end
```

**_create_todos.rb Migration:**

```
class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :todos do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

**_create_profile_todos.rb Migration:**

```
class CreateProfileTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :profile_todos do |t|
      t.string :category
      t.integer :profile_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

**Listing the todos in a User's Profile:**

```
<div id="todos">
  <p><%= @profile.first_name %>&nbsp;has&nbsp;<%= pluralize(@profile.profile_todos.count, 'goal') %>.</p>
  <div id="todo-list">
    <div class="todos_inside">
      <p><%= @profile.profile_todos(:category => 'inside' %>.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="todos_outside">
      <p><%= @profile.profile_todos(:category => 'outside' %>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**add_item to @profile.todos:**

```
<li><%= link_to "#", :class => 'button white' do %><%= @user.profile.stringtoadd %><% end %></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @socjopata mentioned, you're going to need some sort of controller `action` to manage the creation and building of your `ProfileTodo` records.  Since you already created a `ProfileTodo` join model, go ahead and create a `ProfileTodosController`.

More on controllers:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Your `link_to` tag should then make a remote call to the `create` action.  In order to get everything to work properly, you'd most likely need to supply the controller with both the `profile_id` and `topic_id` in order to make the correct RESTful transaction, which means you'll have to supply a parameter hash to your `link_to` tag, which can get kinda messy if you use the url_options.

Look at passing in url_options:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Ultimately, you are creating a new `ProfileTodo` record, so I think it would be a better description of the work being done if you used a `form_for` tag that has hidden fields for the `profile_id` and the `topic_id`.  You can also make forms remote in rails by supplying them with `:remote => true`

Assuming you make an accompanying controller and add RESTful resources to your `config/routes.rb` file, your form for each individual topic would look something like this:

```
<%= form_for(profile_todo_path, :remote=> true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field_tag :profile_id, :value => @user.profile.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field_tag :topic_id, :value => topic.id %>
  <%= f.submit_tag topic.name %>
 <% end %>
```

You can always style your forms, so if you only want a link to be displayed, that should be doable :)

Comment: Or he could possibly make a link, using simple link_to helper that would trigger submitting the form via javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You rather need a remote link pointing to some action, so you can manipulate your todos without refreshing the page. From the docs:

> :remote => true - This will allow the unobtrusive JavaScript driver to
>   make an Ajax request to the URL in question instead of following the
>   link. The drivers each provide mechanisms for listening for the
>   completion of the Ajax request and performing JavaScript operations
>   once they’re complete

As for the other question, you can define scopes you'll use for displaying and counting objects:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a code example that might work with the `link_to` I include above in the update?